# Case insensitive parameter match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to match pets and their owners. Currently I do:

```
MATCH (n:Person) WITH n MATCH (p:Pet{owner: n.name})
RETURN *
```

This works, but doesn't find all my results.

The reason it fails to find all my results is because the letter case between `p.owner` and `n.name` doesn't always match. The Person `name` could be upper or lower case, and the Pet `owner` could be upper or lower case. There is no consistency and sanitising the data before database input is not an option in this scenario.

What I need is to match Persons and Pets while ignoring any casing issues, ideally by lowercasing both the `p.owner` and `n.name`.

I tried using `toLower()` but that doesn't let me lowercase the `owner` in the query (syntax error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like:

```
MATCH (n:Person) 
WITH n 
MATCH (p:Pet)
WHERE toLower(n.name) = toLower(p.owner)
RETURN *
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1 - Convert the relevant strings to lower-case while importing into the DB

This would allow you to keep using the existing query with less processing.

NOTE: the following query is a more concise form of your query. Also, you should consider creating an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on `:Pet(owner)` to fully optimize the query.

```
MATCH (n:Person), (p:Pet {owner: n.name})
RETURN *
```

#### Option 2 - Use a case-insensitive regular expression

If you cannot alter the imported strings for some reason, then you can use Cypher's support for [case-insensitive regular expressions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#case-insensitive-regular-expressions), as in:

```
MATCH (n:Person), (p:Pet)
WHERE n.name =~ '(?i)' + p.owner
RETURN *
```

This option would be *significantly* slower than Option 1, since it cannot take advantage of indexing, and requires expensive text processing for *each and every pair* of `Person` and `Pet` nodes.